# What is the best way to store pairs of strings, make an object or use a class in .NET?

Tags: c#, string, collections, .net-2.0

Don't know whether I'm having a "thick day" - but I just wondered what is the best route here.

Context:

I have a list of fields and I want to store alias names with them (I'm using .NET 2.0 BTW) e.g.

[image]

So its essentially a pair of strings:

> REFERENCE, Ref
>
> COMMUNITY, Community
>
> POST_CODE, Zip Code

... and I'm thinking it seems overboard all the time to keep creating objects for things like this, so should I create a StringDictionary and store the values that way, even though I would not use any of the functionality of the StringDictionary class and I'm not bothered about a key value pair association etc - I just want to keep a pair of strings essentially.

Any help/pointers would be great.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the generic `Dictionary<string, string>` if your "Field Names" are unique.

Otherwise you could use the [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class if you don't mind duplicate keys.

I wouldn't worry too much about whether you use the full functionality of those classes or not.  I think the more important concern should be to write simple, easy to read & maintain code.

Answer (score 55):

The "pair" generic class for .NET is [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx). You would use it like:

```
var strings=new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
strings.Add(Tuple.Create("REFERENCE", "Ref"));
```

A dictionary is a perfectly acceptable substitute if the left-most string is unique (ie a key). You'll get errors otherwise.

As to whether it's better to use the built-in collections or create an actual object, depends on your needs (will you be adding more columns later on? you can't do that with a dictionary approach), how often you use it (if it's a core type, you should probably make a domain model for it) etc.

**Edit:** As to not using any dictionary built-in functionality, that's not true: you're using its binary search algorithm and internal tree construction for lightning-fast look-ups. A list of either `Tuple` or your own type most likely won't have this and it will revert to a linear search.

Answer (score 19):

How about [System.Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)?

Answer (score 8):

what about `Tuple<string,string>`? It's build into .net 4.0 and it's lightweight.

Comment: Please be aware with the duplicate keys, if you wish to avoid.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, it is better to use a custom structure for storing two strings, because: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` and `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` require the method `Add` to add strings into them – it's additional lines of code.
The class `System.Tuple` has only ReadOnly properties – this can be an obstacle.

Example of simple structure:

```
public struct DoppelWert
{
 public string Wert1; 
 public string Wert2;
}
```

Comment: Good solution and I love the field names

Answer (score 4):

For pairs of strings alternatively use [NameValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Surprised, no one mentioned KeyValuePair? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx

Please note that if you are concerned about performance please have a look at this comparison http://www.dotnetperls.com/keyvaluepair

Answer (score 0):

Since C# version 9 you also can use [Target-typed new expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new). It's like Tuples but more readble, because you can give a name for your fields instead of using Item1, Item2...